# Upgraded to Azure SDK 1.8 and DiagnosticMonitor.Start(..) fails

Tags: azure

I upgraded my Azure SDK to use version 1.8 and now I get the following error when compiling.

> error CS0012: The type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudStorageAccount' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

My code code looks like the following:

```
DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", diagConfig);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to manually reference the "Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\2012-10\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll". The reported version on this DLL is version 1.7.0.0 even though it is in the 2012-10 folder.

Comment: As far as I know you also need to change the version in app.config/web.config files if you have listeners added

Comment: That's a good point, it's easy to miss those things when you upgrade SDK's.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out they upgraded the storage library to 2.0 with SDK 1.8, but left the Diagnostics with a dependency to Storage Library 1.7. So stuck in an odd situation, where have spent the time changing code to work with 2.0(quite a few breaking changes documented at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx) but still have to reference the older version for Diagnostics to still work.